# update column values which are null

Tags: sql

I have one column in my sql database named as S-No. 
Which has values like following :

```
S-No
____
1
____
2
____
Null
____
Null
____
3
____
Null
____
Null
____
Null
____
Null
____
Null
____
4
____
Null
.
.
```

Now, i want to write query in such a way that, which S-No column contains Null between 1 to 2, update there value to 1..... And which has Null between 2 To 3, update there value to 2... And so on... eg. 3 to 4 -- update as 3, 4 to 5 --- update as 4, 5 to 6...... I hope you will suggest me the query.. i am not able to write.. Frown | :( i hope you guyz will help.

Comment: Is there an ID column or something that will preserve the order you've shown?

Comment: "Null between 2 to 3" based on what order criteria? By default, there is no order and the fact you get the records in the quoted order is merely a coincidence.

Comment: That doesn't make sense relationally - you can't do that in pure SQL.
 You could do it programmatically.

Comment: You have to have an column by which you have your data  sorted. Then it is possible to do what you want. Otherwise the select will return random order in which case there is no logic behind your thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WITH B AS
(
SELECT ID, (SELECT max(s2) 
            FROM table2 
            WHERE ID < A.ID AND table2.s2 IS NOT NULL) ValueToAssign
FROM table2 A
WHERE s2 IS NULL
)

UPDATE table2
SET s2 = B.ValueToAssign
FROM table2 JOIN B ON table2.ID = B.ID

Comment: Thank you so much.... column names are not like which i am using.... It is working for me..... Cheers........

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's an ID or other column that will preserve order so you know what numbers the `null`s fall between, you could do something like:

```
UPDATE t
SET [S-no] = 
 (
   SELECT MAX(S_no) FROM table WHERE ID < t.ID
 )
WHERE S_no IS null
```

Obviously, either keep a backup or test in a QA environment - no warranties are expressed or implied...